# Simple COM component

Tags: visual-c++, com, atl

Sorry for this stupid questions, but I've never developed COM components. I try to learne interaction between .net and COM though I need to create COM. Questions:
1)Why "STOP" sign appear in solution explorer when I am create COM project in VS2010 using ATL wizard(look at image)?

[image]

2)How can I add my own class for this project?

3)Where can I search simple tutorial for beginners?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Because those are supplementary "Generated Files", they are excluded as not necessary for the build (unless another source file references them explicitly, of course). Stop sign means "excluded".
2. [Adding an ATL Simple Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/893dcd7k%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on MSDN
3. [ATL Concepts and Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ax346b7%28v=vs.100%29), CodeProject